# Buttons activate on creation, then do not work

Tags: python, button, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm neew to this language, and I'm honestly lost.

```
from tkinter import *

class App:

    def __init__(self,master):

        self.var = ""

        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        self.action = Button(frame,text="action",command=self.doAction())
        self.action.pack(side=LEFT)

    def doAction(self):
        print(self.var)

root = Tk()

app = App(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`command=self.doAction()` will call `doAction` at the time the line is run (i.e. at creation). You need to remove the parentheses so that the function isn't called until the button calls it:

```
self.action = Button(frame,text="action",command=self.doAction)
```

To pass an argument (which you know at creation time) to the function, you can use a lambda (anonymous function):

```
self.action = Button(frame,text="action",command=lambda: self.doAction(x))
```

This creates a new function which calls `self.doAction(x)`. Equivalently, you can use a named function:

```
def button_action(): 
    self.doAction(x)
self.action = Button(frame,text="action",command=button_action)
```

Comment: thank you so much. As an extension to this question, how would I use a function which required input?

For example:

`self.action = Button(frame,text="action",command=self.doAction(x))`

`def doAction(self,x):
    print(x)`